# Multiple 4K monitors on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB and I am hoping to attach 2-3 4K monitors to it. My question is, will it be able to handle these monitors? I am not a gamer, so only interested in performance with respect to productivity use, e.g., software engineering work.

Comment: I am pretty sure this will work as I have run 3 4Ks on a lesser video card than the 1060. I expect to be purchasing a machine with a GTX 1060 shortly; if I do I will post an answer confirming.